# Redireccionar a una página no funciona

Tags: php, mysql, mvc, buscador

Estoy haciendo el proyecto de un motor de búsqueda, pero cuando abro la pagina `http://localhost/mvc4/index.php?c=cliente&a=redireccionar&Nombre=carlos` me sale el error:

> Warning: require_once(view/cliente/registrados/carlos): failed to open
>   stream: No such file or directory in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\mvc4\model\cliente.php on line 58
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required
>   'view/cliente/registrados/carlos' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR')
>   in C:\xampp\htdocs\mvc4\model\cliente.php on

El parámetro `$_REQUEST['Nombre']` lo traigo desde el controlador

en el modelo este es el método que redirecciona

```
public function Resultador($Nombre)
{
    try {
                 $stm = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM cliente WHERE Nombre = '$Nombre'");
                 $stm->execute();
                 $pagina=$stm->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                 $ruta = "view/cliente/registrados/";
                 $resultado=$pagina['Nombre'];
                 $solucion = require_once ($ruta.$resultado);
                 return $solucion;
                } catch (Exception $ex) {
            die($e->getMessage());
        }
 }
```

El nombre del cliente cambia, la ruta es dinámica por que depende del nombre del cliente, hay otra forma de crear la ruta dinámica?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te falta definir si es .php, html, otro tipo:

```
public function Resultador($Nombre)
{
    try {
                 $stm = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM cliente WHERE Nombre = '$Nombre'");
                 $stm->execute();
                 $pagina=$stm->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                 $ruta = "view/cliente/registrados/";
                 $resultado=$pagina['Nombre'];
                 $solucion = require_once ($ruta.$resultado.'.php');
                 return $solucion;
                } catch (Exception $ex) {
            die($e->getMessage());
        }
 }
```